# math.h compilation error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '('

Tags: c

I'm trying to compile a fairly large project. A couple files include math.h.  The compilation error I'm getting is:

```
"In file included from math.h:71:0,

mathcalls.h:310:1: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '(' token"
```

I know my math headers have not been changed and they include fine with a "hello math world" program I just wrote, so I'm not sure what the problem is.  THe specific line in the mathcalls.h file that is giving the error is

```
/* Round X to nearest integral value, rounding halfway cases away from
   zero.  */
__MATHCALLX (round,, (_Mdouble_ __x), (__const__));
```

Any clue what the problem is here?

Comment: do you make sure that all headers are included only once by proper ifdefs?

Comment: Are you sure that <math.h> is included at file scope?

Comment: I removed the #include <math.h> from the specific file and it's compiling now. <math.h> is being included in other files.  I still don't understand what the issue is. Math.h has it's own #ifndef to prevent it from being included multiple times. At least it is compiling now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined `round` before including `<math.h>`. Something like this:

```
#define round(x) trunc((x+0.5))
#include <math.h>
```

Compiling the above code with gcc-4.6.2 prints the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/math.h:71:0,
                 from a.c:2:
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h:310:1: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '(' token
```

Comment: Same type of error happens if you define `log2`, or a bunch of other things first that are used in mathcalls.h. This only happens with gcc, not with other compilers (such as Visual Studio).